# Connection between C++ Socket and Java Client

Tags: java, c++, sockets

I'm creating a server app in C++ and client app in Java. I want to exchange 32 bit integer between them.

And I've got a trouble, because when I'm trying send something from Java's client, I get a random answer in C++ server (e.g. I've send '0' and one time I've got a one number, another time I've got different number. I've read about Little and Big Endian coding, but I think it is another issue, because sending '0'  generate a huge value different from 0.

Java Client:

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Socket socket =  new 
Socket(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"),10000);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        out.writeInt(0);
    }
}
```

C++ Server:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){


    int port = 10000;
    string ip_addr = "127.0.0.1";
    int domain = AF_INET;
    int type = SOCK_STREAM;
    int protocol = 0;

    int stopCondition = 0xFFFFFFFF;


    int socketHandle;
    struct sockaddr_in address;

    int clientSocketHandle;
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;
    size_t clientAddressSize;

    int buffer;


   if((socketHandle=socket(domain,type,protocol))<0)
        cout<<strerror(errno);

    address.sin_family = domain;
    inet_pton(domain,ip_addr.c_str(),&address.sin_addr);
    address.sin_port=htons(port);


    if((bind(socketHandle,(struct sockaddr *)&address,sizeof(address)))<0)
        cout<<strerror(errno);


    if (listen(socketHandle, 1) < 0)
        cout << strerror(errno);


    if ((clientSocketHandle = accept(socketHandle, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddress, (socklen_t *) &clientAddressSize)) < 0)
        cout << strerror(errno);


    do {

        if (recv(clientSocketHandle, &buffer, sizeof(int), 0) > 0)
            cout<<buffer<<endl;

    } while (buffer != stopCondition);


    if(shutdown(clientSocketHandle,SHUT_RDWR)<0)
        cout<<strerror(errno);


    if(shutdown(socketHandle,SHUT_RDWR)<0)
        cout<<strerror(errno);

    return 0;
}
```

How should I implement my client in Java to work properly with my C++ server?

Comment: Warning: `recv(clientSocketHandle, &buffer, sizeof(int), 0) > 0` doesn't guarantee a you get all the bytes you asked for. Don't just test `recv`'s return value for failure. Test to make sure you got the right number of bytes. `MSG_WAITALL` may help you here. Java, if I'm remembering correctly, sends integers big endian by default while C++ will send integers in the native endian. Make sure these match.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain your C++ implementation uses a 32 bit `int`? I suggest using `int32_t` to be sure you have the size right.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks a lot, I really appreciate it. You're right, the problem was `MSG_WAITALL`. I didn't use it, and propably, I didn't get all the bytes. Integer was 32 bit, but now I am using `int32_t` like you suggested.

Comment: @user4581301, I would like to ask one more question. Now, if I use `MSG_WAITALL` I cannot receive data in loop. I can only get first data, then `recv` function doesn't change my buffer. Do you know how to deal with it?

Comment: Don't have a good answer for you. `recv(clientSocketHandle, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), MSG_WAITALL)` should keep receiving until the cows some home. Bundle your problem up with a good [mcve] and ask a new question is my suggestion.

Comment: `cout << buffer << endl;` isn't going to print a binary integer. The problem ist at the Java end. You need convert the received binary to ASCII.